# How to access web assembly from inside a Typescript unittest?

Tags: typescript, webassembly

I have a WASM file compiled from C++ that does some signal processing on audio data for a Typescript library. It's normally loaded in the browser with a GET request and then accessed from Javascript.

I'm trying to write a mocha unittest for the Typescript library that wraps it, but since Typescript doesn't directly load it, and I've ever only loaded it from inside a browser from a server, which doesn't exist in a unittest, how would Typescript access the WASM?

My Typescript package looks like:

```
dist
    mypackage.js
    mypackage.d.ts
    signal.wasm
src
    mypackage.ts
    signal.wasm
test
    test.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: How does your TypeScript read the file is it doesn't load it directly?

Comment: @Dean James Honestly, I'm not sure. It's created by emscripten, which auto-generates a loader that issues a web request to retrieve it from a URL on the localhost.

Comment: Ok, maybe your unit test should not be testing that as it's not your code and unit tests shouldn't be performing network requests as they'll be brittle. This is something an integration test should cover instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing my library that is using WebAssembly modules with Jest and [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest). You can use the built-in [WebAssembly](https://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-webassembly-in-node.js.html) object in Node.js for instantiating your signal processing module. You just need read your `.wasm` file with one of the [file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) methods, and then pass it as a buffer to `WebAssembly.instantiate`.